# Run options: --seed 16186

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

When I execute `ruby -Itest test/models/usuario_test.rb` to make a mini test show the message:

> Run options: --seed 16186

I want to remove the message but is not a critical bug, it's just a presentation improvement.

thanks for now!

Comment: Just taking a gues here, but try: `ruby -Itest test/models/usuario_test.rb --seed 16186`

Comment: I had tried this, but it did not disappear